# Multiple DataTemplates for one ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Imagine multiple object types in one Listbox. Both have different look and presented information. If I add any of them in ObservableCollection it displays them fine in ListBox.

```
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:DogData}"  >
    <Grid...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:CatData}"  >
    <Grid...
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I want users to be able to press a button and switch view to see more detailed information and there templates which provide it

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateDogDataWithImages"  >
    <Grid...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateCatDataWithImages"  >
    <Grid...
</DataTemplate>
```

but I can assign only one

```
AnimalsListBox.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["TemplateDogDataWithImages"] as DataTemplate;
```

I don't want to have one and have a bunch of triggers in it.

I have researched DataTemplateSelectors
http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Is there a better way?  Is there a way to switch default templates for each data type so I could avoid DataTemplateSelectors? 
On click of the button how do I select TemplateDogDataWithImages and TemplateCatDataWithImages as default ones and cliking other button use TemplateDogDataSimple and TemplateCatDataSimple?

Comment: DataTemplateSelectors are probably the simplest way.

Comment: You can't assign a `DataTemplate` to the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` property... the clue is in its name. Besides, the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` property is for the defining the `ListBoxItem`, not the data item. Perhaps you meant the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property?

Comment: @Sheridan Yes, you are right, meant ItemTemplate. I am changing it

Answer (score 0):

I think a selector is easier (less code), but if you really want to use triggers, maybe something like this?

```
    namespace WpfApplication65
{
    public abstract class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class DataBase : NotifyBase
    {
        bool m_showDetailed;
        public bool ShowDetailed
        {
            get { return m_showDetailed; }
            set
            {
                m_showDetailed = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowDetailed");
            }
        }
    }

    public class DogData : DataBase { }
    public class CatData : DataBase { }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<DataBase> Items { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Items = new List<DataBase>() { new DogData(), new CatData(), new DogData() };

            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication65.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication65"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:CatData}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="basic">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is the basic cat view" />
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="detailed">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is the detailed cat view" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>

            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    Margin="2"
                    Padding="2">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_Presenter"
                                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource basic}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Show Details"
                              IsChecked="{Binding ShowDetailed}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowDetailed}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Presenter"
                            Property="ContentTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource detailed}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:DogData}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="basic">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is the basic dog view" />
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="detailed">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is the detailed dog view" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>

            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Blue"
                    Margin="2"
                    Padding="2">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_Presenter"
                                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource basic}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Show Details"
                              IsChecked="{Binding ShowDetailed}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowDetailed}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Presenter"
                            Property="ContentTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource detailed}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Window>
```